# Is it possible to enable only specific C++ language features in gcc?

Tags: c++, gcc

I have a c++14 project that currently targets gcc 7.2, and I am looking to backport code from a project that targets c++17.  This project makes extensive use of `if constexpr`.  gcc 7.2 supports `if constexpr` with the --std=c++1z flag, however it brings along all the other (at the time) experimental C++17 features.

Is there a way to enable only specific language features, in this case `if constexpr`, in gcc 7.2?

Comment: Just don't use the ones you don't want to use?

Comment: While good advice, sometimes you don't know you are using something only available in C++17.  What is considered an aggregate and all that entails comes to mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it is not possible. It's all or nothing.

There is some limited level of control over language dialect in g++
https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C_002b_002b-Dialect-Options.html

If these dialects are used it can raise a warning and you can turn this warning into an error.

Another way could be to create plugins for clang-tidy or clang-query to check your C++ code base do not use any construct you don't want, but it becomes a rather large work to achieve the intended purpose.